# JS Error Detection Across All Browsers Using Cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, automated-tests, capybara

`JSErrorCollector is` cool, but can only be used with **FireFox**.
 Anyone know how I can detect `js` errors across my site, **using any browser**?